# what is this? it used to have a recessed light attached to it

Tags: kitchens

[image]We bought this house and it has some weird wiring throughout. This is at the end (I hope) of a series of 3 light fixtures in the kitchen. It was attached to a recessed light fixture in some cabinetry above the kitchen sink. We would like to replace the light but 1. when we pulled the old light fixture off, it shorted the other lights in the kitchen and 2. i'm not completely sure its legal/safe to mess with. Any useful info or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It's a surface mounted junction box that connects the wires in conduit to the NMC ("Romex" is a brand name) cable going back into the wall. It may or may not meet code, but it's a particularly ugly hack job...

Comment: is it possible to strip it and attach a light fixture directly or should i get an electrician?

Comment: Without opening it up and seeing what's actually happening inside it, and without knowing where the cable goes, we can't even guess.